# Access object class Python in List

Tags: python, list, oop

I have a question about accessing the object class from the list in python, I have compared my cases to the questions that were on stack overflow but that didn't work. I present the problem as follows

- 1. Class Booking has the properties start_date, end_date

```
from datetime import *

class Booking:

    def __init__(self):

        self.year = int(input("Enter the Year: "))
        self.month = int(input("Enter the Month: "))
        self.day = int(input("Enter the Day: "))
        self.start_date = datetime.now()
        self.end_date = datetime(self.year, self.month, self.day)
```

- 2. Class Room is abstract class

  - I create a `booking(list)` to store the object of the `Booking` class which is initialized when the `Room` class is initialized.

```
from abc import *
from booking import Booking

class Room(ABC):
    bookings = []

    def __init__(self, price, capacity):
        self.booking = Booking()
        self.price = price
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.bookings.append(self.booking)

    @abstractmethod
    def is_booked(self, start_date, end_date):
        pass
```

- 3. `SingleBed` inherits `Room(ABC)` with price = 150 and capachity =2

```
from room import Room

class Singlebed(Room):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Singlebed, self).__init__(150, 2)

    def is_booked(self, start_date, end_date):
        if start_date >= end_date:
            print("EndDate must be greater than StartDate")
        is_Booked = False
        for check_booking in self.bookings:
            is_Booked = check_booking... (I wants to access objects.end_date in class Booking is saved in bookings)

single1 = Singlebed()
single2 = Singlebed()
single3 = Singlebed()
single4 = Singlebed()
single5 = Singlebed()
```

#### My question: How do I access object.end_date which is initialized with single1, single2, ...

Comment: `self.booking.start_data`?

Comment: I don't understand, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over your self.bookings so "check_booking" is your Booking instance and contains the attribute start_date, end_date, year, month, day

```
   def is_booked(self, start_date, end_date):
        if start_date >= end_date:
            print("EndDate must be greater than StartDate")
        is_Booked = False
        for check_booking in self.bookings:
            is_Booked = check_booking.start_date
```